# How to limit file size in binary field odoo

Tags: file, odoo, limit

I have a binary field and I want to limit upload file size to less than 1MB. How can I do that.

```html
binary_field = fields.Binary(string="Upload Image")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file size of binary fields is limited with [max_upload_size](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L1974) which is set to the session `max_file_upload_size` or to the default value of 128 Mb, it can be changed using the system parameter [web.max_file_upload_size](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/models/ir_http.py#L31-L35)

The max upload size is hard coded and can't be specified from a binary field

You can extend the existing binary field and set the max file size based on a field attribute.

***Example:***

```
/** @odoo-module */

import fieldRegistry from 'web.field_registry';
import basicFields from 'web.basic_fields';
import session from 'web.session';


var CustomFieldBinaryFile = basicFields.FieldBinaryFile.extend({
    init: function (parent, name, record) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if(this.attrs.max_upload_size) {
            this.max_upload_size = this.attrs.max_upload_size;
        }
    },
});

var CustomFieldBinaryImage = basicFields.FieldBinaryImage.extend({
    init: function (parent, name, record) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if(this.attrs.max_upload_size) {
            this.max_upload_size = this.attrs.max_upload_size;
        }
    },
});

fieldRegistry.add('custom_binary', CustomFieldBinaryFile);
fieldRegistry.add('custom_binary_image', CustomFieldBinaryImage);
```

Add the js file to the `assets` entry in the manifest file under `web.assets_backend`

To use it set the following attributes on the binary field tag: `widget` and `max_upload_size`

***Example:***

```
<field name="binary_field" widget='custom_binary' max_upload_size="1048576"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is perfectly working. But I want to know is if I use binary field as image widget, how can we limit this binary image field.

Comment: You can use the same logic with the [FieldBinaryImage](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L2084) widget